# What's the difference between gdal_cachemax and setting the cache size with -wm in gdalwarp?

Tags: qgis, gdal

I'm trying to get better performance out of gdalwarp, and am wondering if there is any difference between setting **gdal_cachemax** and using the **-wm** option in gdalwarp?

Answer (score 7):

In document https://trac.osgeo.org/gdal/wiki/UserDocs/GdalWarp the difference is explained in section "**Will increasing RAM increase the speed of gdalwarp?**"

-wm sets the memory reserved for working buffers of gdalwarp, gdal_cachemax is used for setting the size of i/o buffers. There are more technical details in the section "**Warp and Cache Memory: Technical Details**".